# How to directly access the IP camera without username and password in the external web application in Node red?

Tags: node.js, node-red

I have created a Node red application and integrated my IP camera live stream in it. But every time I open my page, it asks for the username and password of the camera. I read the camera's documentation, it says we can directly access the camera if we use url like "http://username:password@host/".

But I cannot pass such URL in my iframe or img src because my browser will block such request. So, I read the node red documentation for http-proxy and I got some solution from there.
https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-http-proxy

It says if we use http-in node along with a http-proxy node, we can directly access IP camera. I followed all the steps. But it still asks for the username and password.

[image: This is my Http-in and http-proxy node]

[image: Http-in node]

[image: http-proxy node]

```
<img src="http://localhost:1880/mjpeg_test" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

And this is my img tag in the template node.

I have tried changing the authentication protocol to basic. Earlier it was digest. But it still asks for the username and password in both the cases.

Please share your answers as I am new to Node red

Comment: "...my browser will block such request..." -- says who?  That's a perfectly valid URL.  A browser doesn't have the right to ignore it.

Comment: Subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials (e.g. `https://user:pass@host/`) are blocked. I am getting this error on console if I directly put that url in my iframe or img tag

Comment: You appear to have included the credentials in the privacy node twice, Gaffer you used a network scanner to see what it's actually being sent to the camera?